# Pick a random item from a list

Tags: javascript, random

I'm learning Javascript and i need some help. I have a list. I've tried to make a list, where you can, by the click of a button, get a random song from that list, but it doesn't seem to work. My list is down below, what am i doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <button type="randomSong">Random Music</button>
  <input "randomSong" id="randomSong">
</div>

<script>

var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");

var randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random()*song.length)];

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well for one there's no `sange` variable. The other problem is that you're not doing anything with the selected song, the button, or the input (which has malformed HTML btw).

Comment: Your JS code works, you just need to put it back into the HTML and then you're done.

Answer (score 9):

Your code is almost correct. Here is a proper version:

HTML

```
<div>
  <button type="randomSong" onclick="randomSong()">Random Music</button>
  <input name="randomSong" id="randomSong">
</div>
```

Modifications:

- add an attribute name to the input (you had `"randomSong"` without any attribute key)
- use an `onclick` callback, so that something happens when you click your button

JS

```
var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");

function randomSong() {
  var randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];
  document.getElementById('randomSong').value = randomSong;
}
```

Modifications:

- wrap your random code into a function (the one referenced by the `onclick` attribute of your button)
- assign the result to the input

Answer (score -1):

The method below shows how to get a random item in javascript:

```js
const songs = ["song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6"];

function findSong() {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
  document.getElementById("randomSong").setAttribute("value", songs[randomIndex]);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="findSong();" type="randomSong">Random Music</button>
  <input "randomSong" id="randomSong">
</div>
```

Comment: Shitsu's answer is more accurate, please upvote him since i don't have enough reputation yet

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Since Math.random() returns a float between 0 included and 1 excluded, multiplying it by (song.length -1) (=5 in this case) will give a number between 0 included and 5 excluded, and flooring it will give an int between 0 and 4, completely ignoring the last item.